# Dockerized Python Flask REST API displays "The page isn't working

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to run Flask in Docker. The containers seem to be running but the browser can't connect.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services: 
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8.2
COPY ./src /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["run.py"]
```

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_filename)

    from app import api_bp
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app("config")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try to go to `http://localhost:5000/api/Hello`, I get:

[image: chrome page isn't working error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it adding the host to the `app.run`:

```py
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```